# Dispute rejected edits

Tags: support, edits

I edited someone's post (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8559008) to correct some grammar and spelling mistakes. I also removed the kinda useless phrase "Please help me!!!!".

It got approved by some user, but then the OP rejected it with "This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive."

This was the first review that user (who has currently a total reputation of 1) did. I don't think he even knows what the rejection reason means.

Is there a way to dispute a rejection like that?

Comment: Some people just won't be helped.

Comment: You can always flag for moderator attention (custom reason, including as much detail as possible). I have made the edit and commented asking the user not to reject legitimate edits.

Comment: I feel like that user didn't really earn that Custodian badge he got for this...

Comment: Just so you know, that was the post author exercising a binding reject vote, hence why they're reviewing suggested edits with a rep of 1.  As a new user, they probably just aren't accustomed to having their posts improved by others, and react negatively even when their post needs the help.

Comment: Had something very similar happen with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31008009/2415822.  The OP was being rude, so I just gave up on helping them and moved on.

Comment: Only if I can dispute your disputation of the rejection. This way madness lies...

Comment: @JAL - It's not often I get to flag a comment for rudeness. OP, it's not necessary to do so but some people have had success with explaining that the original text violates one of the site rules/norms. I've done this when deleting recommendation requests tacked onto an otherwise OK question.

Comment: Even better, the rejecting member's only question on the site is on-hold.

Comment: I think it could also be in the comment-wording of the edit: "*removed useless 'HELP ME!!!'* ".  Some new users , not knowing general SO policy on *fluff*, might make this personal: "You calling my wording useless?!" And as a result, they make an unwarranted reject of the edit.  Then again, sometimes it's simply as @TZHX said... I've had this happen before where the author told me SO was "not for learning English".

Comment: To be fair to the guy, it *is* possible that he simply didn't know what the hell he was supposed to do and what this whole edit thing even means. There hasn't been any actual word from him yet; he picked the rejection from a list (and I wouldn't be surprised if it was the default choice)

Comment: I so wish any of my regular SO questions would get that many upvotes^^

Answer (score 38):

If an author is rejecting appropriate edits, or rolling back edits that are very clear improvements to the post and edits that are appropriate as per the site's editing guidelines, then flag the post for moderator attention.

The user is vandalizing their own posts, which is not appropriate behavior.

It's not a situation that comes up all that often, so there aren't really tools for non-moderators to deal with the situation.  Mods, on the other hand, *do* have tools to deal with users vandalizing their own posts, so if you explain the situation in a flag they can look at the situation and take whatever action(s) they feel are appropriate.

Answer (score -40):

As the author I feel I should have a final say on what I sign my name under. That's why the author's vote is binding. I think that's a good thing. People can suggest changes, but in the end it's your post. I feel that in order to be comfortable with other people changing my posts, and those changes possibly taking effect without me knowing about it, it's important that I can override/change them.

Obviously that might sometimes mean people seem to hold on to something you really don't understand, or don't appreciate, but in the end it's all about striking the right balance, which sometimes means letting go. Better to have to let go of someone else's stuff than of your own.

Comment: Eh, the author's vote is not binding because they should have final say. It is binding because they are in the best position to be able to say if an edit clarifies or fixes something in their post or not, as they are the ones who originally wrote it. I don't think we should spread that rumor that the author always has final say as it's not always true.

Comment: `As the author I feel I should have a final say on what I sign my name under.`  This in not the case here.  As soon as you've submitted the content it is no longer solely yours, it is licensed to the public to work on.  You do *not* have the right to vandalize your own post. `I feel that in order to be comfortable with other people changing my posts, and those changes possibly taking effect without me knowing about it, it's important that I can override/change them.` You *can* override/change them *if they're harmful*.  If they're helpful/appropriate then you're just vandalizing your own post.

Comment: I think it might be a wrong perspective on how stackoverflow works. A post here is not meant as an expression of your opinion. Instead it is meant to help people with problems. Not only the author, but also all others who might find that post later on. Thus the post should have the best quality possible, not the wording preferred by a prideful OP.

Comment: @Dakkaron actually SO is meant to have a high quality repository of programming questions. That those programming questions help someone, is an collateral effect.

Comment: This is a very valid point; the author's name is under the post, and other people will perceive this as the author's opinion and judge the author for it. That's why there is a reject reason for an edit that changes the intended meaning of the author. And the author is the only one who can judge whether an edit changes the intended meaning of the author, so in that sense, the author does have the final say. And that's good. As long as something hasn't been turned into a wiki.

Comment: @Braiam Are you seriously suggesting SO's 'purpose' is to be a high-quality but utterly useless repository - but by lucky coincidence, such a hq repo is actually useful after all?

Comment: @OllieFord yeah, nobody should really care to help someone, as long as they produce high quality content. If you are into helping someone, the quality will be gone in a flash.

Comment: @Braiam My point is that HQ content was always going to (intended to) help people, since the primary source of traffic to SO is anonymous users consuming it.