# Do enough rejected edits flag an account?

Tags: support

I suggested what I believe was a really good edit at https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34517650 to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53502745/9731176 which was rejected, and thus [I had to split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501357/python-change-instagram-profile-picture-with-requests/53502745#comment134774066_53502745) into https://stackoverflow.com/a/76433821/9731176.

My situation is identical to [Dispute rejected edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297682/9731176), even the supposed rejection reason.

This worries me for two reasons – I don't want to have my improvement flagged for plagiarism, and also don't want an edit ban, but [there doesn't appear to be an edit rejection appeal process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333741/9731176). (This rather puts me off bothering to spend time editing...)

Consequently, does enough rejected edits cause anything adverse for my account?

Comment: I find it odd that you changed the numbering in that post to start at 0, rather than 1; why step 0?

Comment: Why would your improvement be flagged for plagiarism if it wasn't plagiarized?

Comment: There is a temporary edit-ban, yes. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280175/why-did-i-get-temporary-ban-for-editing-questions. As long as you don't keep getting rejected edits, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: 10 edits rejected out of 24 is not a good track record. Perhaps you should reflect on what was considered the problem with those 10.

Comment: if an author doesn't want your edits and repeatedly undoes them, why keep trying?

Comment: @ThomA, I didn't change it to *start* at zero, that's just a consequence of StackOverflow's Markdown interpreter starting automating list numbering at 0. Having solely 0-delimited lists informs the processor to automatically number the list; it should improve maintainability.

Comment: @SecurityHound, it *does* contain much of the linked answer, albeit solely because that's necessary to answer the question. Is it only plagiarism if it's done in bad faith? I worry that a moderator, if an unsuspecting user flags my answer, might not take the time to consider my intention.

Comment: Unfortunately, @PresidentJamesK.Polk, the responses are usually similar to the one that I have quoted; they're at least not enough that I've gained an idea of any underlying problem with my edits after some basic evaluation of the rejected ones. Note that at least two come from this specific answer anyway.

Comment: @beedell.rokejulianlockhart - Plagiarism is Plagiarism.  If you purposefully plagiarized content, or do it by accident, it will be deleted for plagiarism if it's flagged. I still question, how is an edit proposal to an existing contribution, going to be a risk of introducing content that is plagiarized? You should quote and cite external resources.  **If you are introducing content to an existing contribution, as an edit proposal, that could be seen as being plagiarism and will rightfully be rejected by the community**

Comment: *"I didn't change it to start at zero, "* yes, you did  you changed the 1., 2., 3., Etc to 0., 0., 0. . *You* did that... You submitted the edit. Did you not review your edit before you submitted it?

Comment: Separately, you can avoid plagiarism by following our [referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: @beedell.rokejulianlockhart - Your edits were rejected because they were NOT an improvement.  You are actually mistaken about the Markdown editor.  You also added sentences, that were NOT written by the original answer author, which is concerning of course. Ultimately the author, who is a very experience Python contribution on Stack Overflow, decline your edit proposal.  If that turns you off on making edit proposals, then you should revaluate, if you want to do edit proposals knowing the community will sometimes disagree with your edit proposals in the future.

Comment: "that's just a consequence of StackOverflow's Markdown interpreter starting automating list numbering at 0." - I have not observed it to do any such thing.

Comment: The CommonMark specification implemented here starts numbering at the number used for the first item in the list, then increments each subsequent item (regardless of what numbers were used for those items in the raw Markdown source). Therefore, if you start numbering from 0, the first item will be numbered as 0 in the rendered version. cc @Karl

Comment: Ah, I see. Never actually occurred to me to try that. Somehow, despite being a programmer. :)

Comment: Lists shouldn't normally start with 0. If it is was for maintainability, they could all start with "`1.`" instead of "`0.`". But both options go against the principle of Markdown: ***Readable source***. The same (and misleading) number widens the gap between the Markdown source and the rendered page. The post is very unlikely to be changed again and manual renumbering is not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks, @CodyGray-onstrike. I'll use 1 from now onward.

Answer (score -8):

[Do enough rejected edits flag an account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425043/do-enough-rejected-edits-flag-an-account/425044?noredirect=1#comment960611_425043)

> There is a temporary edit ban, yes.

---

Per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297732/9731176, it appears that

> If an author is rejecting appropriate edits, or rolling back edits that are very clear improvements to the post and edits that are appropriate as per the site's editing guidelines, then flag the post for moderator attention.

Comment: Did you mean to add this to your question? It doesn't seem to be an answer to whether or not it does anything to your account.

Comment: I would not expect this flag to get validated as 1) This seems to be a one-time thing and 2) Changing the numbered list to start at 0 is not a good change, so the edit is of questionable quality already.

Comment: Yeah, I think I answered the wrong question. I've included an actual answer now, @GeneralGrievance. Thanks.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425043/do-enough-rejected-edits-flag-an-account/425044#comment960617_425043 should provide some useful information about your second statement. Thanks for the help.